# EBUSY error when downloading and executing a .exe file with Node.js

Tags: node.js, spawn

I'm trying to download an executable file with Node.js and execute it as soon as the file is downloaded. I should launch it using the `spawn` method because I want the new process to be detatched. This is what I have done:

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream("myex.exe")
http.get("http://host/myex.exe", function(response) {
     response.pipe(file);
     const subproc = spawn('myex.',['param1', 'param2'], {
        detached: true,
        stdio: 'ignore'
    });
    subproc.unref();
});
```

The problem is that when node.js tries to launch the executable in a new process, an exeption arises:

```
Error: spawn EBUSY
```

I tried to execute in the same way the .exe file without downloading it and the process is correctly created. If I execute it with the `exec` function it works perfectly but I cannot detach the new process.  What is the problem and what could be a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is file is occupied, my way is  ,  use settimeout ,wait  for  a while  , and then use execFile